# Closing alert dialog in android on press of button for first time

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

### What i am doing:

- I am launching a dialog using below code
- On click i want to close the dialog

### What is happening;

- Dialog is closing, but i have to click the ok button twice(looks like alert is popping twice but closing for the second time i press ok)

### What i want to do:

- I want to close the dialog on click of ok for the first time

---

```
   public void open(String custMsg){

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setMessage(custMsg);
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        dialog.cancel();
      }
    });
    alert.show();

}
```

Comment: Call `dialog.dismiss()` instead of `dialog.cancel();`

Comment: i tried but same result !.... as i said dialog will close but looks like dialog itself if popping twice ......

Comment: Show that event where you open your dialog ..

Comment: in onResume() i am popping this alert dialog

Comment: check how many times you're calling `open()`

Comment: Okay thats why the problem. Cause every time while your in your activity ur onResume() will call and pop up appear.

Comment: you may be calling dialog twice onCreate() and onResume() check it and revome in onResume() method

Comment: @Devrath Is it solved now?

Comment: @user3556371 ....... Resolved this but have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27577887/1083093(similar to present behaviour)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to make the dialog pops up in `onResume()`. `onResume()` is called everytime the window is focused again. When a dialog pops up, the window loses its focus. When you cancel the dialog, the activity is focused again and `onResume()` is executed and shows the dialog again.

Call the dialog somewhere else and it will work (`onStart()` for example)

Comment: Resolved this but have a look at this question stackoverflow.com/q/27577887/1083093(similar to present behaviour)

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is.

You have to move your code for open pop up to some where because whenever you enter in that your activity your `onResume()` will be call and every time dialog pop up will be open which is wrong. So just move that code somewhere where it execute properly.

***NOTE:*** Call `dialog.dismiss()` instead of `dialog.cancel();`

Comment: [+1] ... Resolved this but have a look at this question stackoverflow.com/q/27577887/1083093(similar to present behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

Try this better

```
public AlertDialog open(String msg) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,
                AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.about_title)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();

        return builder.create();
    }

    }
```

But you also need to create the dialog and i cannot see where you create it

Comment: If you check above comments then you can see that who says and what is not working.