# Dialog is not closed dialog.dismiss() when navigating backand forth to settings screen

Tags: android, android-dialog

### What is happening::

1. dialog is popped
2. I click ok - > it leads me to settings screen
3. Now i press back button
4. When i come back dialog button is still there
5. again i click ok
6. again it leads me to settings screen
7. this repeats, dialog is never closed

---

### What i am trying to do:

1. dialog is popped
2. I click ok - > it leads me to settings screen
3. Now i press back button
4. When i come back dialog button should have closed

---

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        createInstances();
        //set up notitle 
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        //set up full screen
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main_splash_screen);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        open(getResources().getString(R.string.location_not_enabled));
    }

   public void open(String custMsg){

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setMessage(custMsg);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                locationValidationDone=true;
                dialog.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: try add `final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();` and dismiss `dialog` in Ok click

Comment: @shayanpourvatan ... This dosent work ..... only way to resolve this requirement is to place it in oncreate as prakash suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dialog is used in`onstart()` please use in `oncreate()`,

when your back to your actvity it's called the `onstart()` and `onresume()`,

please read the `activity lifecycle`[lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(!start_dialog)
    {
        start_dialog = true;
        open(getResources().getString(R.string.location_not_enabled));
    }
}
```

Comment: So this perticular validation has to be done on oncreate itself ? ... no way to do in onstart() ?

Comment: if you want use in onstart() , set flag and reset

Answer (score 0):

In the ok button code instead of

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

use it

```
alert.dismiss();
```

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder doesn't have *dismiss* method

Comment: @hanish sharma ...... I didn't downvote the answer but .. as OneWay said is correct !

Comment: its okk but but its working for me 
just use 
alert.dismiss();
instead of 
 dialog.dismiss();

Comment: @hanishsharma .... I still agree with oneWay comment ... but This dosent work ..... only way to resolve this requirement is to place it in oncreate as prakash suggested